# PHP MySQL Backup script on IIS Server

Tags: php, mysql, iis, backup

Bit of a newbie, so please excuse the lack of terminology. . . .
I have a PHP script to backup a MySQL database "dbjobs".
I've tried nearly everything I can but can't get it to work.
It works if I run the $command directly from the Command Prompt on the server, but everytime I try to run the PHP version, I get an HTTP 500 error.

```
<?php
$backupFile = "DBJobs_" . date("Y-m-d");
$command = "\"mysqldump.exe\" --opt -hlocalhost -uUser -pPasswword dbjobs > c:/backup.sql";
$result = system($command);

if ($command !== false) {
echo "<p>Backup file created!</p>";
}
else {
  echo "<p>There was a problem!</p>";
}
?>
```

I have tried the exec() function instead of system() but still does the same.
Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely both a path issue (the web server doesn't know where the executable is) and a permission issue. Typically, IIS isn't able execute a shell (cmd.exe) and so isn't going to be able to run the executable, so it would have to have permissions to get a shell and to run the MySQL utility.

Your other alternative is to have the database do it for you with a select statement that writes to an output file.

Comment: Bear in mind on the first option, the web server must have permissions to write to the directory and on the second option, the database server must have write permissions.

Comment: Do the alternative, exec and system are both usually disabled and shouldn't be allowed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options to try are:

- full path to the mysqldump.exe in the $command line of code
- You might try backticks `$command` instead of system (backticks key also has the tilda symbol when you shift)
- Could be a permissions issue???

Answer (score 0):

You have to grant read/execute permissions to the account under which IIS is running on C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe. [Check this out.](http://blog.arithm.com/2008/01/04/running-windows-commands-from-php-over-iis/)